# How do I create TypeScript nice name for project package

Tags: typescript, module

I am trying to make my project CoolRunnings easier for consumers.

```
index.ts
-src
--view
---a.ts
---b.ts
--controller
---a.ts
```

what do i need to do to have consumers use my project in the following way.

```
import CoolRunnings;
let view = new CoolRunnings.view.a()
let controller = new CoolRunnings.controller.a()
```

I would like to make sure that my types work after.

For example
`let aView: a = <a> new b();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the items to the default export in `index.ts` (or whatever your projects entry point file is)

```
// index.ts
import viewA from './view/a'
import viewB from './view/b'

import controllerA from './controller/a'
import controllerB from './controller/b'

const CoolRunnings = {
  view: {
    a: viewA,
    b: viewB,
  },
  controller: {
    a: controllerA,
    b: controllerB,
  },
}

export default CoolRunnings
```

Now from other app using your package:

```
import CoolRunnings from 'cool-runnings'
new CoolRunnings.view.a()
```

Comment: I have a problem with types. for example. `function atype() : CoolRunnings.view.a { return new CoolRunnings.view.a();}`

Comment: If you have a link to some documentation that would be awesome :)